# How can I use scrapy to fetch the data through proxy, at the same time I do not use middlewares

Tags: proxy, scrapy

I am using scrapy to fetch the data, I bought some proxies. I read the scrapy [doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), I found that if I want to use proxy, I should write `middlewares`. Now my question is how can I use proxy without `middlewares`? I tried like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    name = my_name
    password = password
    proxy = my proxy
    return[
           FormRequest(url,formate={'account':my_name,'password':password},
                      meta={'proxy':proxy},
                      callback=self.after_login)
        ]
def after_login(self, response):
    response.xpath(.....)
```

I got `TypeError:argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`
Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/think/sjs-project/sjs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 542, in connect
    timeout=self._timeout, bindAddress=self._bindAddress)
  File "/home/think/sjs-project/sjs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 482, in connectTCP
    c = tcp.Connector(host, port, factory, timeout, bindAddress, self)
  File "/home/think/sjs-project/sjs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1165, in __init__
    if abstract.isIPv6Address(host):
  File "/home/think/sjs-project/sjs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 522, in isIPv6Address
    if '%' in addr:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks very much.

Comment: what is the type of the `proxy` variable? it should be a string with this format `'http://some_proxy_server:port'`

Comment: yes, its format is right.

Comment: The "host" part of your proxy seems to be empty. can you paste the value you are using?

Comment: Thanks very much, the proxy I used was disabled, now I have changed another one. Please, I have another question, is there a way to get the cookies? I tries `response.cookies`, but I got error. Thanks

Comment: The error is `HtmlResponse object has no attribute 'cookies'`

Comment: Check [`Response.headers`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?#scrapy.http.Response.headers) and use `response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')`

Comment: Thanks, I got `[]`, I think it is because I did not set cookies value